# Why is my cloned git history different from the origin's one?

Tags: git

I want to extract a directory from my git repository and clean both history.

I followed the method explained [here](http://www.geekaholic.org/2010/02/splitting-git-repo.html):

```
$ git clone --no-hardlinks foo.repo bar.repo
$ cd bar.repo
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter bar HEAD  -- --all
$ git reset --hard
$ git gc --aggressive
$ git prune
```

This worked great :) The `git log` is also clean. :) After cleaning the `remote`, it looks as if I had the thing in a separate repository from day 1.

Then in the origin repository, I followed:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf bar" --prune-empty HEAD
```

But here, the history is not clean, I can see all the commits in `bar`. (edit: only with `git log --all`, the history is clean without option `--all`)

However, if I clone this repository into a new one, the history is clean! How come is that?

What did I miss that the `git clone` did for me upon cloning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found how to clean the history: `git reflog expire --all`.

The question is still open for anybody who can explain what happened...

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following two git commands

```
git remote update
git remote prune origin
```

Comment: I don't understand. That would be commands to type in the cloned repository, am I wrong?